# jQuery focus between .click() events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

This is homework, just declaring it now.

I have to load a 'quiz' via XML (completed successfully), and generate td cells (done) to display said questions (not done, test data instead).

Here is my source code for the javascript

```
var selected;
var $cell;
var $cell2;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#getTitle").click(function() {
        selected = $("#quizname>option:selected").text();
        $("#quiztitle").html(selected+" Quiz");
        $("#quiz2").html(selected+" Quiz");
        murl = "quizdata.xml";
        $.ajax({type:"GET",
            url:murl,
            success:loaddata,
            cache:false,
            dataType:"xml",
            data:selected,
            error:ajaxerror
        });
    });
});

var $xml;
function loaddata(respobj,status,xhr) {
    //to do:
    //dynamic td creation for each xml question
    $("#questions").empty();
    $xml = $(respobj).find("quiz:contains("+selected+")");
    for (var i=0;i<$xml.attr("qnum");i++) {
        $('<tr>').attr("id","questions"+(i+1)).appendTo("#questions");

        $("<td>").attr("id","question"+(i+1)).appendTo("#questions"+(i+1));
        $("#question"+(i+1)).html((i+1)+". "+$xml.find("question[num='"+(i+1)+"']").text());
        $("#question"+(i+1)).addClass("th.thirty");

        $("<td>").attr("id","blank_question"+(i+1)).appendTo("#questions"+(i+1));
        $("#blank_question"+(i+1)).addClass("question");
        $("#blank_question"+(i+1)).html("Put Answer Here");

        $("<td>").attr("id","answer"+(i+1)).appendTo("#questions"+(i+1));
        $("#answer"+(i+1)).addClass("question");
        $("#answer"+(i+1)).html((i+1)+". "+$xml.find("answer[num='"+(i+1)+"']").text());

        $("#answer"+(i+1)).click(selectCell);
    }
}

function selectCell() {
    $cell = $(this);
    $cell.css("background-color","red");
    for (i=0;i<$xml.attr("qnum");i++) {
        $("#blank_question"+(i+1)).click(function() {
            $cell2 = $(this);
            $cell.css("background-color","lightgray");
            temp_text = $cell.text();
            temp_id = $cell.attr("id");
            $cell.attr("id",$cell2.attr("id"));
            $cell.text($cell2.attr('id'));
            $cell2.attr("id",temp_id);
            $cell2.text(temp_id);
            $("#answer"+(i+1)).unbind("click");
            $("#answer"+(i+1)).bind("click", function() {
                selectCell();
            });
        });
    }
}

function swapCell() {
    $cell.css("background-color","lightgray");
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
}

function ajaxerror(xhr,status,error) {
    $("td#desc").attr("class","");
    $("td#desc").html("xhr="+xhr);
    $("td#desc").append("<br /><br />status="+status)
    $("td#desc").append("<br /><br />error="+error);
}
```

My issue is (try it here: [HomeWork Link](http://php.radford.edu/~jalexander/jQuery/hw2/hw2.html)) that the first time you click the first cell, swap it with the second, it works. However, it only works every OTHER click and swap, which makes me think that there are some binding issues or focus issues because I need it to swap seamlessly. Is there an obvious error in the code or am I missing a specific focus/bind event?

Thanks!

Edit: the values being displayed AFTER swapping are the cells ID attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling "jquery recursive .click binding" I found that instead of .click() I changed it to .live() and that works perfectly.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.